# Merge two databases or keep both databases separately

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, asp.net-web-api

I am currently working on a Web API.
As of now, I am thinking of merging 2 databases from MSSQL Server into 1 database but I am unsure whether it is beneficial for me to do that. 
The 2 databases I am planning to merge are Users Database and the database that is mainly working on the assets.
I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages of merging databases and keeping the databases separately.

Comment: Depends on usages. What entities are in databases, how are they related and accessed.

Comment: Someone planned these databases to be separate. What was the reason for that? May be, they wanted to keep authentication separate from transactions. And use Users database later for more authentication across applications. It's about requirement, not your thought, that you should need to merge databases.

Comment: Apart from being **subject to opinion**, it's impossible to say without more details

Comment: A database can be viewed as a worksheet with tables.A table is a view of a sheet with a subset of columns.Tables reduces the amount of memory in a database because a value in a column can be made a key.  When a key is used in a 100 rows the name is enter only once in the database with 100 links reducing memory.If you have two databases you really have two worksheets on one server which is a workbook.The only real advantage of combining is if you can reduce the amount of memory by combining keys. Combining databases can be a disadvantage be it take more time to get data from a larger database.

Comment: The users database will be used for authentication and authorization. Whereas, the other database will used for CRUD of the data from there.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what type of database you are working with and what is actual requirement.

I will suggest you to use one DB as it is better to manage in the code and you only need on DBContext. Otherwise you can use two DB and there is no problem until you use in optimized way.